# React hot reload doesn't work on arrow function

Tags: reactjs, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

I have a very simple React component and I noticed that my react hot reload doesn't work if I write my functions inside components like this

```
class Profile extends Component {
  renderSkills = () => skills.map(skill => (
    <div key={skill}>
      <Button>{skill} + 3</Button>
    </div>
  ))

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.renderSkills()}</div>
    )
   }
}
```

but it works fine if I write it like this

```
renderSkills() {
    return skills.map(skill => (
      <div key={skill}>
        <Button>{skill} + 3</Button>
      </div>
    }
```

So the hot reloading only doesn't work inside that function, if change something inside that function. If I change anything outside of it , it works normally.

In console I see that change was applied it just doesn't show up on the screen untill I reload the page.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` to support the following syntax.

```
renderSkills = () => skills.map(skill => (
    <div key={skill}>
      <Button>{skill} + 3</Button>
    </div>
  ))
```

Comment: it's included. The syntax is working and code is working fine. Problem is with hot reloading when changing something inside that function.

Comment: I spend some time googling the issue and I found this pull request for `react-proxy` which is used by `react-hot-loader`. It seems the hot-reload library does not support class method as arrow function at the moment.

https://github.com/gaearon/react-proxy/pull/8#issuecomment-133668399